# Eigenfunction for solving wave equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, eigenfunctions

$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos\frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{2L}(c_{1n} cos\frac{(2n-1)\pi t}{2}+c_{2n} sin\frac{(2n-1)\pi t}{2})$, $n=1,2,...$ $x\in[0,L]$

The ICs are

$u(x,0)=p(0)x$, $u_t(x,0)=p'(0)x$

Applied the first IC, I got $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_{1n} cos\frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{2}=p(0)x$, then I don't know how to tackle with this $\sum$, anyone can please help me to walk through these two ICs?

Comment: You haven't correctly evaluated $u(x,0)$ -- there's still a $t$ hanging around in your expression.

Comment: I corrected, thank you!

Comment: Have you thought of expanding x in a fourier series and comparing coeffs.